# Is there anything similar to Bitlocker/Veracrypt for Mac besides Filevault?

Tags: security

My objective is to prevent someone from logging in my Mac via bruteforce or using some deep underground security vulnerabilities that's not disclosed to the general public. With my Windows PC, I was able to setup Veracrypt where I have to type an [initial password](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33122660/32680457-0397500e-c66b-11e7-93f4-fe2c26bb576e.jpg) when I turn my PC on then I have to type a 2nd password just to login.

With Mac, I already have Filevault and firmware password turned on. Is there a way I can have my mac ask for an [initial password similar to veracrypt](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/33122660/32680457-0397500e-c66b-11e7-93f4-fe2c26bb576e.jpg) to decrease my chances of someone bypassing my [Mac's login screen](https://appletoolbox.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/Login-screen-for-macOS-Big-Sur-1280x720.jpg)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204455

Comment: Care to explain why 2 passwords are better than 1 well chosen password that both unlocks the disk and logs you in.  You can use VeraCrypt after login to secure your super secret data. And, what is your risk model, from whom are you trying to protect?